# Is there any clear way to do a list of AND NOT conditions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

now I have a json object with following sample:

```
{
    "a1": "xxx",
    "a2": "xxx",
    "a3": "xxx",
    "b": "xxx",
    "c": "xxx",
    "d": "xxx",
    "e": "xxx",
    "f": "xxx"
}
```

**which a1,a2,a3 do not always have the same key**
(it may change key name as b1,b2,b3 or any other key name etc.)

---

Therefore, when I want to get these key's value, I will add the following condition inside a **for-loop**:

```
if (key!="b" && key!="c" && key!="d" && key!="e" && key!="f") {}
```

but I want to have a clear way to do this condition.
Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: please add some use cases and the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple conditions like this, I like to use an array and check if the value is in that array or not. Slightly more readable.

```js
var key = 'a1';
var key2 = 'b';

if (['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'].indexOf(key) === -1) {
  console.log(key);
}

if (['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'].indexOf(key2) === -1) {
  console.log(key2);
}
```

```js
var list = {
    "a1": "xxx",
    "a2": "xxx",
    "a3": "xxx",
    "b": "xxx",
    "c": "xxx",
    "d": "xxx",
    "e": "xxx",
    "f": "xxx"
};

var key;

for (key in list) {
  if (['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'].indexOf(key) === -1) {
    console.log('Key not in array', key);  
  } else {
    console.log('Key in array', key);  
  }
};
```

Comment: If you're using the array more than once, might be best to store it in a variable

Comment: Thats a good point, but there is no indication that this array would need to be used more than once. I only added it twice for a better example

Comment: This is the solution that I wanted. Thanks @CarlMarkham

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object as blacklist for the unwanted keys.

```js
var data = { a1: "xxx", a2: "xxx", a3: "xxx", b: "xxx", c: "xxx", d: "xxx", e: "xxx", f: "xxx" },
blacklisted = { b: true, c: true, d: true, e: true, f: true };

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    if (!blacklisted[key]) {
        console.log(key)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I am correct you have some value and you call it a key. And you wanna go trough all object properties and check if every property holds that value?

It's quite simple, you need to use for..in loop and compare key to every property of the object and if one differs you exit with false.

You have not specified what happens when you are given the empty object? Since I don't know the context, I assumed function should return false on empty objects (hence the check at bottom).

To put it in code:

```
var key = "xxx";

var  keys = {
  "a1": "xxx",
  "a2": "xxx",
  "a3": "xxx",
  "b": "xxx",
  "c": "xxx",
  "d": "xxx",
  "e": "xxx",
  "f": "xxx"
};

var checkKeys = function(objectWithKeys, key) {
  var numberOfProperties = 0;

   for (prop in objectWithKeys) { 
    if (objectWithKeys.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
     numberOfProperties++;
     if (objectWithKeys[prop] !== key) return false;
    }
   }

  if (numberOfProperties !== 0) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

As I assume you are new to JS, I will explain 2 crucial parts in the solution:

`for (property in object)` is a variation of standard for function. It best practice to iterate object properties in this way.

`if (objectWithKeys.hasOwnProperty(prop))` is verry important check. By default when you ask for property if object doesn't have it, it looks up the prototype chain. Object.hasOwnProperty ensures the property you got from for..in iteration is defined in that object, not some object your object inherited from.